# How to Convert FragmentActivity to Fragment?

Tags: android

I am new in Android. I'm building an app with sliding bar format and a part of sliding bar is one Fragment. I can convert Activity to Fragment but now I'm have a Fragment Activity and I want to convert it to Fragment. Can I do it in Android. 
Thanks for your help.

```
   import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class GoogleMapV2 extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.googlemap_layout);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are
                                                    // not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.mapGoogle);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service
            // LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // TextView tvLocation = (TextView) fa.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
        // tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" +
        // longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MyLocation" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapGoogle"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
      />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I used to try so hard to convert Fragment Activity to Fragment like convert Activity to Fragment but I got InflateException. I don't know if there is any way to convert Fragment Activity to Fragment in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you can't because a fragment is a piece of an application's user interface or behavior that can be placed in an Activity. It's belong to an Activity. So Activity can't be converted to Fragment.

More information view links below:

- [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)
- [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#Fragments)

Comment: I found the way to convert Activity to Fragment in here http://spacetech.dk/android-convert-activity-to-fragment.html. Is it wrong?

Comment: You can do as the web said, and tell me if it is possible to convert activity to fragment

Comment: I follow this web and I can convert Activity to Fragment. Nothing error happened with me. However, my problem is convert FragmentActivity to Fragment.

Comment: Well, `FragmentActivity` is a sub class of `Activity`, if it is ok that for Activity, it is also ok for `FragmentActivity`. You can convert it by following the web's instruction